# Bitbake the latest Gstreamer in Yocto Morty

Tags: gstreamer, yocto, bitbake, recipe

I would like to bitbake the latest Gstreamer in Yocto Morty, but the error has occured and could not implement the Gstreamer.

I found the gstreamer 1.12.2 recipe at https://github.com/dv1/meta-gstreamer1.0.
So I put meta-gstreamer1.0 directory in sources directory and add BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-gstreamer1.0 " to build_fb/bblayers.conf.
Then I bitbaked fsl-image-gui and following errors are occured.

```
    ERROR: /home/***/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-gstreamer1.0/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-omx_1.12.2.bb: Error executing a python function in <code>:

    The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was:
    File: '<code>', lineno: 13, function: <module>
         0009:__anon_35__home_***_var_fslc_yocto_sources_poky_meta_classes_devshell_bbclass(d)
         0010:__anon_108__home_***_var_fslc_yocto_sources_poky_meta_classes_sstate_bbclass(d)
         0011:__anon_45__home_***_var_fslc_yocto_sources_poky_meta_classes_blacklist_bbclass(d)
         0012:__anon_158__home_***_var_fslc_yocto_sources_poky_meta_classes_siteinfo_bbclass(d)
     *** 0013:__anon_30__home_***_var_fslc_yocto_sources_meta_gstreamer1_0_recipes_multimedia_gstreamer_gstreamer1_0_omx_inc(d)
    File: '/home/***/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-gstreamer1.0/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-omx.inc', lineno: 22, function: __anon_30__home_***_var_fslc_yocto_sources_meta_gstreamer1_0_recipes_multimedia_gstreamer_gstreamer1_0_omx_inc
         0018:EXTRA_OECONF += "--disable-valgrind --with-omx-target=${GSTREAMER_1_0_OMX_TARGET}"
         0019:
         0020:python __anonymous () {
         0021:    omx_target = d.getVar("GSTREAMER_1_0_OMX_TARGET")
     *** 0022:    if omx_target in ['generic', 'bellagio']:
         0023:        # Bellagio headers are incomplete (they are missing the OMX_VERSION_MAJOR,#
         0024:        # OMX_VERSION_MINOR, OMX_VERSION_REVISION, and OMX_VERSION_STEP macros);
         0025:        # appending a directory path to gst-omx' internal OpenMAX IL headers fixes this
         0026:        d.appendVar("CFLAGS", " -I${S}/omx/openmax")
    Exception: TypeError: getVar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'expand'

    ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing /home/***/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-gstreamer1.0/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad_1.12.2.bb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/***/var-fslc-yocto/sources/poky/meta/classes/base.bbclass", line 375, in __anon_656__home_***_var_fslc_yocto_sources_poky_meta_classes_base_bbclass(d=<bb.data_smart.DataSmart object at 0x7fb7a8dcff98>):
             pkgconfig = (d.getVar('PACKAGECONFIG', True) or "").split()
    >        pn = d.getVar("PN", True)

  File "/home/***/var-fslc-yocto/sources/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/data_smart.py", line 569, in DataSmart.getVar(var='PACKAGECONFIG', expand=True, noweakdefault=False, parsing=False):
         def getVar(self, var, expand, noweakdefault=False, parsing=False):
    >        return self.getVarFlag(var, "_content", expand, noweakdefault, parsing)

  File "/home/***/var-fslc-yocto/sources/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/data_smart.py", line 737, in DataSmart.getVarFlag(var='PACKAGECONFIG', flag='_content', expand=True, noweakdefault=False, parsing=False):
                     cachename = var + "[" + flag + "]"
    >            value = self.expand(value, cachename)

  File "/home/***/var-fslc-yocto/sources/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/data_smart.py", line 410, in DataSmart.expand(s="     ${GSTREAMER_ORC}     ${PACKAGECONFIG_GL}     ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'bluetooth', 'bluez', '', d)}     ${@bb.utils.filter('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'directfb vulkan', d)}     ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'wayland', 'wayland egl', '', d)}     bz2 curl dash dtls hls neon rsvg sbc smoothstreaming sndfile uvch264 webp ", varname='PACKAGECONFIG'):
         def expand(self, s, varname = None):
    >        return self.expandWithRefs(s, varname).value

  File "/home/***/var-fslc-yocto/sources/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/data_smart.py", line 400, in DataSmart.expandWithRefs(s="     orc     gles2 egl     ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'bluetooth', 'bluez', '', d)}     ${@bb.utils.filter('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'directfb vulkan', d)}     ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'wayland', 'wayland egl', '', d)}     bz2 curl dash dtls hls neon rsvg sbc smoothstreaming sndfile uvch264 webp ", varname='PACKAGECONFIG'):
                 except Exception as exc:
    >                raise ExpansionError(varname, s, exc) from exc

bb.data_smart.ExpansionError: Failure expanding variable PACKAGECONFIG, expression was      orc     gles2 egl     ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'bluetooth', 'bluez', '', d)}     ${@bb.utils.filter('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'directfb vulkan', d)}     ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'wayland', 'wayland egl', '', d)}     bz2 curl dash dtls hls neon rsvg sbc smoothstreaming sndfile uvch264 webp  which triggered exception AttributeError: module 'bb.utils' has no attribute 'filter'


Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

I found the error "Exception: TypeError: getVar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'expand'" is fixed in Yocto 2.3(Pyro) at https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3314.
Furthermore, YP core says gstreamer version for Yocto Morty is 1.8.3 (see https://www.yoctoproject.org/downloads/core/morty22 updates tab).

Do these things mean that we cannot implement gstreamer 1.12.2 or later version in Yocto Morty? Are there any way to do it? Do we have to use Yocto Pyro or later version if we want to implement gstreamer 1.12?

Environment

> Yocto Morty (2.2.1) https://github.com/varigit/variscite-bsp-platform/tree/morty#variscite-release-notes

PS:

I rewrite getVar and bitbake proceeded.However I got following error.Would someone help me?

```
ERROR: gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-1.12.2-r0 do_populate_sysroot: The recipe gstreamer1.0-plugins-base is trying to install files into a shared area when those files already exist. Those files and their manifest location are:
   /home/***/var-fslc-yocto/build_fb/tmp/sysroots/imx6ul-var-dart/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstrawparse.la
 Matched in b'manifest-imx6ul-var-dart-gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad.populate_sysroot'
 /home/***/var-fslc-yocto/build_fb/tmp/sysroots/imx6ul-var-dart/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstrawparse.so
 Matched in b'manifest-imx6ul-var-dart-gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad.populate_sysroot'
Please verify which recipe should provide the above files.
The build has stopped as continuing in this scenario WILL break things, if not now, possibly in the future (we've seen builds fail several months later). If the system knew how to recover from this automatically it would however there are several different scenarios which can result in this and we don't know which one this is. It may be you have switched providers of something like virtual/kernel (e.g. from linux-yocto to linux-yocto-dev), in that case you need to execute the clean task for both recipes and it will resolve this error. It may be you changed DISTRO_FEATURES from systemd to udev or vice versa. Cleaning those recipes should again resolve this error however switching DISTRO_FEATURES on an existing build directory is not supported, you should really clean out tmp and rebuild (reusing sstate should be safe). It could be the overlapping files detected are harmless in which case adding them to SSTATE_DUPWHITELIST may be the correct solution. It could also be your build is including two different conflicting versions of things (e.g. bluez 4 and bluez 5 and the correct solution for that would be to resolve the conflict. If in doubt, please ask on the mailing list, sharing the error and filelist above.
ERROR: gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-1.12.2-r0 do_populate_sysroot: If the above message is too much, the simpler version is you're advised to wipe out tmp and rebuild (reusing sstate is fine). That will likely fix things in most (but not all) cases.
ERROR: gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-1.12.2-r0 do_populate_sysroot: Function failed: sstate_task_postfunc
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/***/var-fslc-yocto/build_fb/tmp/work/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.12.2-r0/temp/log.do_populate_sysroot.99466
ERROR: Task (/home/***/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-gstreamer1.0/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base_1.12.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot) failed with exit code '1'
ERROR: gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-1.12.2-r0 do_package: Error executing a python function in exec_python_func() autogenerated:

The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was:
File: 'exec_python_func() autogenerated', lineno: 2, function: <module>
     0001:
 *** 0002:split_gstreamer10_packages(d)
     0003:
File: '/home/***/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-gstreamer1.0/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gst-plugins-package.inc', lineno: 6, function: split_gstreamer10_packages
     0002:PACKAGESPLITFUNCS_append = " set_metapkg_rdepends "
     0003:
     0004:python split_gstreamer10_packages () {
     0005:    gst_libdir = d.expand('${libdir}/gstreamer-${LIBV}')
 *** 0006:    postinst = d.getVar('plugin_postinst')
     0007:    glibdir = d.getVar('libdir')
     0008:
     0009:    do_split_packages(d, glibdir, '^lib(.*)\.so\.*', 'lib%s', 'gstreamer %s library', extra_depends='', allow_links=True)
     0010:    do_split_packages(d, gst_libdir, 'libgst(.*)\.so$', d.expand('${PN}-%s'), 'GStreamer plugin for %s', postinst=postinst, extra_depends='')
Exception: TypeError: getVar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'expand'

ERROR: gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-1.12.2-r0 do_package: Function failed: split_gstreamer10_packages
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/***/var-fslc-yocto/build_fb/tmp/work/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.12.2-r0/temp/log.do_package.99465
ERROR: Task (/home/***/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-gstreamer1.0/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base_1.12.2.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are migrating recipe for older version of Yocto into a newer, you must be facing consequences of [this change in Yocto](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#migration-2.1-expand-parameter-to-getvar-and-getvarflag-now-mandatory): *expand* parameter (the second one) to **getVar()** and **getVarFlag()** has become mandatory ([from bitbake user manual for morty](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.2/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#functions-for-accessing-datastore-variables)), previously it was defaulted to **False**. So, you should correct all occurrences of these operations and add at least **False** as a second argument.

Comment: Thank you. I checked the site https://github.com/dv1/meta-gstreamer1.0 and found morty branch. Although there werer many bitbake errors, I successed to bitbake gstreamer 1.12.4.